# Improve efficiency of multiple string comparison (regex?)

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have the following code which I am trying to speed up:

```
private bool IsValidProduct(string productName)
        {
            return (productName.IndexOf("something", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1 &&
                    productName.IndexOf("whatever", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1 &&
                    productName.IndexOf("blah", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1 &&
                    productName.IndexOf("keyword", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1 &&
                    productName.IndexOf("etc...", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1);
        }
```

There are around a dozen words that I am checking for currently.

What is the fastest way of doing this?

Comment: one thing: this *is* quite readable....I would prefer this above a regex ;)

Comment: Have you actually *profiled* that code as being too slow? Do that first before trying to optimize.

Comment: Are you sure it's the bottleneck?

Comment: There are timers around various parts of the algorithm and the parts that are taking the most time are the string checking and manipulation. I should point out that this function is called tens of thousands of times as part of a data sanitation class for third party data. As the number of interations increases over time, we have noticed a significant slowing of the process, hence the need to optimise.Any speed gain is more than worth a slight decrease in readability.

Comment: Have you looked at the page Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx)?

Comment: @The Flower, then do try a RegEx. They can be really fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are around a dozen words that I am checking for currently.

I think that means you don't really have a performance problem.

But a regex solution would look like :

```
var r = new Regex("something|whatever|blah", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
return ! r.ismatch(productName);
```

Which is at least as readable in my opinion. And I'm sure it's faster but you will have to profile.

For performance, you would have to cache & re-use the RegEx instance. Creating it is the expensive part.

Comment: If you really want to use regex and you want speed then consider creating the regex at class scope.  See this for more details: http://www.acorns.com.au/blog/?p=136

Answer (score 5):

Regex is not a good idea, try something like this:

```
List<string> keywords = new List<string>
    {
        "something",
        "whatever",
        "keyword",
        "etc"
    };

return keywords.All(keyword => !productName.Contains(keyword));
```

Comment: @Henk Holterman: I mean not a good idea for this issue. OP just want to check if *productName* contains the keyword. *Regex* is overkill.

Comment: Where is the overkill? If the list is configurable than this looks better. For a hardcoded list I think my RegEx is more readable.

Comment: You need a `ToLowerInvariant()` on `productName`

Answer (score 2):

You could transform `productName` to lower case and then use `.Contains`. Should be a bit faster. Since you're using invariant culture this should work(With some cultures it doesn't).

```
string lowerProductName=productName.ToLowerInvariant();
return !(lowerProductName.Contains("1")||
         lowerProductName.Contains("2"));
```

There are some techniques to make it much faster, but it's unlikely you need them. And they are more complicated to implement. Especially since you only have a few short keywords.

But I agree with Cody that you should profile first and find out if it's really this code that's slowing you down.

Answer (score 0):

What about using an implementation of [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm) which is intended to search for a set of keywords in a target text?

Or what [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm) which is the gold standard for fast string search but will only search for a single string at a time?